# Not able to import json from commandline for Python

Tags: python, json, command-line

I am currently tring to work with import a json input that is accepted by Python through a commandline argument and I am trying to save the different values to JSON to a list. I am having issues with my code given below and have attached both the code and the error I get below. Any help much appreciated.

```
import sys
import json
def lookup1 ():
    jsonData = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
    print jsonData
    jsonList = [jsonData['proxy'],jsonData['OS']]
    print jsonList

lookup1()
```

The error is given below:

```
$ python dynamicMapper.py '{'proxy':1,'OS':2}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dynamicMapper.py", line 9, in <module>
    lookup1()
  File "dynamicMapper.py", line 4, in lookup1
    jsonData = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

The commadline argunet that I give is `python dynamicMapper.py '{'proxy':1,'OS':2}'`
I am not able to find out what is causing this error and if my approach is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is working fine, you just need to call it the right way:

```
python dynamicMapper.py '{"proxy":1,"OS":2}'
{u'OS': 2, u'proxy': 1}
[1, 2]
```

In JSON the strings are quoted with double quotes instead of single quotes. You also need to quote the string passed to script so that shell understands it being a single argument.

Comment: ah, thanks! I guess what was wrong was the way I called it. I was using `python dynamicMapper.py {'proxy':1,'OS':2}`. I though single and double quotes were interchangeable. Probably not in a dict, Is that right?

Comment: @lordlabakdas You're not passing a dict to to the script but a string containing JSON that your script then parses with `json.loads`.